# Multiple events probability

Tags: probability

Which option has a higher probability to win? In both cases you get 10 coins in order to have the possibility to win 15\$. Once you lost all your coins or got payed out 15\$, the game is over.

**Option 1**: Bet 5 coins for a payout of 15\$ with the odds of winning being 1:3. If you fail, you can retry with the remaining 5 coins, but with odds of 1:4.

**Option 2**: Bet 5 coins for a payout of 5\$ with odds of 1:1. If you fail, you can retry with the remaining 5 coins, but odds of 1:2.
If you win any of these two tries, your coin balance is reset to 10 coins and you can repeat the game, but this time for a payout of 10\$ and two tries with odds of 1:2 and 1:3 (if you fail the first try).

My thought process goes as follows:

**Option 1**: The chances to win either attempt one or two are `1 - (0.75 * 0.8) = 0.4`. So I have a 40% probability of winning the 15\$.

**Option 2**: What are my chances here? How do I calculate it?

Comment: The rules are not clear.  In the first option, it looks as if the *payout* on a win is $\$15$ (for a profit of $\$10$) but in the second option it looks like the *profit* on a win is $\$5$.  After all, nobody is placing a bet where a loss means you lose your money and a win just means you get your bet handed back to you.  What is intended here?

Comment: I suggest, phrase all the bets in terms of wagered amount and payouts.  Thus an even money bet could be a $\$5$ wager with a potential payout of $\$10$.  That standardizes the language.

Comment: (1) Let us first be clear: By **chance** are you meaning **probability** or **odds in favor**  Ratios like 1:3 are normally used for **odds** while  fractions like $1/3$ are used for **probabilities** (2) also, is "win" *net* win or *net win* + stake ?

Comment: Post edit:  what you wrote doesn't make sense.  Nobody would wager $\$5$ in hopes of winning a $\$5$ payout.

Comment: Again, you are using words carelessly, and the confusion makes it impossible to sort out the question.  Think about it:  would you bet $\$5$ on a coin toss if a win meant you got your $\$5$ back?  Presumably you meant *profit* in that case.  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: If it is from a quiz, obviously you have not quoted the question exactly. And if you have quoted it exactly, it is not worth looking at.

Comment: I rephrased and specified the entire question, I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the rules (not clear, but the latest round of edits help), then here is how to calculate the probability of winning under Option $2$.

To be clear:  "winning" here means that you acquire $\$15$.  All other outcomes are losses.

So, consider the first round in option $2$.  Your goal in this round is to win $\$5$ (if you fail, then you have already lost the game).  The probability of failing is $\frac 12\times \frac 23=\frac 13$ since you need to lose *both* attempts.  Thus, with probability $1-\frac 13=\frac 23$ you will make it out of the first round with $\$5$ and with $10$ tokens to wager.

Now, trusting you made it to the second (and final) round of option $2$, your probability of losing both tries is $$\frac 23\times \frac 34=\frac 12$$

To put this together:  to win under option $2$, you must win both rounds and the probability of that is $$\frac 23\times \frac 12=\frac 13$$

Which makes this the less attractive option, trusting, again, that I have understood the rules correctly.  It might be different if, say, the question was "which option has the higher expected value" since it is likely enough that in Option $2$ you win the first round (so get $\$5$) but fail to win the second round.  In the above, I scored that outcome as a loss, but it is certainly a "better" loss than walking away with nothing.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer that I was looking for. What would the expected value of both options be?

Comment: The calculations I wrote out contain all the information you need to answer that (at least for option $2$, but for option $1$ there are no "partial" wins).  Just go through the possible scenarios.

Comment: Expected value:
Option 1: 0.4 * 15 = 6; Option 2: 0.66 * 5 + 0.33 * 10 = 6.66

Comment: Right.  So, Option $2$ looks better from that perspective.